# Concatenating 2 bytes in one short in java

Tags: java

How can I concatenate 2 byte values into a short value in java?

This:

```
byte b1 = 0xAC;
byte b2 = 0xAD;
short pixelShort = (short) (b1<<8 | b2);
```

does not work, as the result is 0xFFAD. Why is this?

Comment: I did not see an _exact_ duplicate myself. b2 is negative, | operation uses ints, so (int)b2 messes up the high byte. `(short) (b1 << 8 | (b2 & 0xFF))` or such.

Comment: I was trying to answer my own question but it was marked duplicate before I could post ^^;

Comment: `ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {b1, b2}).getShort()`